# CSS transition of height for injected content into a DIV

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-transitions

I'm having a following template:

```
<div class='content'>
    {{content}}
</div>
```

And following style:

```
.content {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 300px;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
```

Please note that `{{content}}` will grow or shrink (technically to extend a card to show more information or hide it). I've already set the css `transition` and it does work when manually setting a different `height` to the element. However when more content is injected into `content` no transition is made, just a plain old resizing. Any help of getting the transision right?

See [following plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SzVsj3tXd6bckUbkXJKb?p=preview)

Thanks,

Amit.

Comment: I think the reason is that what you are changing the text content but repaint/reflow does not fires

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that's quite normal, transitions apply only to changes to the CSS, not for computed changes.

One option might be to have a nested `div`, set `overflow: hidden` on the outer one, then get the computed height of the inner one and set it on the outer one to get the transition.

CSS:

```
#outer {
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    width: 300px;
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="more" onclick="increase();">More</button>
<button id="more" onclick="decrease();">Less</button>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function increase()
{
    var o = document.getElementById('inner');
    var t = o.innerHTML;
    for (var i=0 ; i<20;i++)
        t += " lorem ipsum";
    o.innerHTML = t;
    adjustHeight();
}

function decrease()
{
    var o = document.getElementById('inner');
    o.innerHTML = "lorem ipsum";
    adjustHeight();
}

function adjustHeight()
{
    var i = document.getElementById('inner');
    var o = document.getElementById('outer');

    o.style.height = window.getComputedStyle(i).height;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnts7w1f/

Comment: I like this solution since it offers an solution by design. I kind of had the feeling that transitions only work over declared CSS properties, but your solution offers me a clean way to handle this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Excellent, it helped me to solve the problem I had, simple and functional. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With the help of @jcaron answer I managed to sort this in a react component. So when the 'activeSubsection' button is clicked the useEffect hook is run.

```
    const [topicsHeight, setTopicsHeight] = React.useState("0px")
    const topicsDiv = React.useRef();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        
        setTopicsHeight(topicsDiv?.current?.offsetHeight + "px")
    
    }, [activeSubsection])

    {!hideTopics && 
        <div style={{ overflow: "hidden", height: topicsHeight, transition: "0.2s" }}>
          <Topics ref={topicsDiv} className="largeScreen">
            {!!subsectionTopics && subsectionTopics.sort((a, b) => a.node.slug.localeCompare(b.node.slug)).map((topic, index) =>
              <Link key={index} href={'/'+slug+'/'+topic.node.slug} scroll={false}>
                <Topic
                  active={activeTopic == topic.node.slug} transition={true} bold={activeTopic == topic.node.slug}
                >
                  {topic.node.title}
                </Topic>
              </Link>
            )}
          </Topics>
        </div>
    }
```

Ovbiously that's not the full component but hopefully enough to give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Well... There's a trick you can do for that... I don't know if it will fit your needs.

The css transition effect is applied on css properties that have a previous value, and then change. Though you are indeed changing the content's height of the div, the actual css property `height` is not explicitly changing. That's why you don't get the animation.

A workaround is to find the inner height of the div and then set it to the element, causing it to animate. I've created a function for that, and added a `span` to control the inner size of the div.

Just call the function on every change:

```
<div class='content'>
  <span id="height-control">
    {{ctrl.content}}
  </span>
</div>
```

JS function:

```
  var spn = document.getElementById("height-control");
  var UpdateHeight = function () {
      var h = spn.offsetHeight;
      spn.parentNode.style.height = h + "px";
  };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/p6QRAR5j4C8d0d0XRJRp?p=preview